# I want to visit homepage as a guest but facing login page continuously in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, user-interface, authentication, middleware

I'm facing login page again and again when try to go to the homepage. I didn't add any middleware to homepage route but still I'm facing this issue.

My Login Controller

```
protected $redirectTo = '/';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function redirectToProvider()
    {
        return Socialite::driver(request()->provider)->redirect();
    }


    public function handleProviderCallback()
    {
        $provider = request()->provider;
        $providerUser = Socialite::driver($provider)->user();
        if($providerUser->getEmail() == null) {
            $user = User::where($provider . '_id', $providerUser->getId())->first();
        } else {
            $user = User::where('email', $providerUser->getEmail())->first();
        }
        if($user && $user->$provider . '_id' == null) {
            dd('test');
            $user->update([$provider . '_id' => $providerUser->getId()]);
        }
        if(!$user) {
            $user = User::create([
                'email' => $providerUser->getEmail(),
                'name' => $providerUser->getName(),
                $provider . '_id' => $providerUser->getId(),
            ]);
        }

        auth()->login($user, true);

        return redirect($this->redirectTo);

        // $user->token;
    }

    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        session()->put('previousUrl', url()->previous());

        return view('auth.login');
    }

    public function redirectTo()
    {
        return str_replace(url('/'), '', session()->get('previousUrl', '/'));
    }
```

I don't know the issue is in controller or in routes.

Routes

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomePageController@index')->name('welcome');
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/login/{provider}', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider');
Route::get('/login/{provider}/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

I can visit the homepage only when I logged in but I want to see it as a guest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The home route is protected, you can see this in construct method of HomeController. To make it unprotected, try to comment the line in constrct method.
To prevent errors in home view, you have to edit this view too.